# DataObject updated with write() not reflected in CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I have a class 'listing' which has the following fields:

```
static $db = array(
            ...
            'Left' => 'Varchar',
            'Top' => 'Varchar'
            ...
    );
```

I am grabbing these to display over a map with:

```
function getListings(){
        $sqlQuery = new SQLQuery();
        $sqlQuery->setFrom('ListingCategory_Listings');
        $sqlQuery->selectField('STLC.Title AS cTitle, STLL.Title AS lTitle, Listing_Live.ID AS lID, ListingCategory.ID as cID, Phone, Email, Website, Filename, Top, Listing_Live.Left, STLC.ID AS catID');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('Listing_Live', '"ListingCategory_Listings"."ListingID" = "Listing_Live"."ID"');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('SiteTree_Live', '"Listing_Live"."ID" = "STLL"."ID"', 'STLL');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('ListingCategory', '"ListingCategory_Listings"."ListingCategoryID" = "ListingCategory"."ID"');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('SiteTree_Live', '"ListingCategory"."ID" = "STLC"."ID"', 'STLC');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('File', '"ListingCategory"."IconID" = "File"."ID"');
        $sqlQuery->addWhere('"Listing_Live"."ID" IS NOT NULL');
        $sqlQuery->setOrderBy('ListingCategory.ID', 'ASC');
        $result = $sqlQuery->execute();
        $dataObject = new ArrayList();
        foreach($result as $row) { 
            $dataObject->push(new ArrayData($row)); 
        }
        return $dataObject;
    }
```

I have a function to update the left and top values of the objects (fired via AJAX by dragging and dropping an instance of the object on the front end):

```
function updatePoi(){
        $left = $_POST['left'];
        $top = $_POST['top'];
        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        if ($poi = DataObject::get_one('Listing', '"Listing"."ID" = '.$id)){
            $poi->Left = $left;
            $poi->Top = $top;
            $poi->write(); 
            return 'success';
        }else{
            return 'error';
        }
    }
```

These are definitely being updated, as on page refresh, the objects are reflecting the updated Top and Left values, however I am showing these fields in the CMS but they are showing blank here. Also, when I save the object in the CMS, the Left and Top values are cleared and I have to reposition them again in the front end.

Does anyone understand why this is happening?

UPDATE: It seems that the write() only updates the Listing_Live table, not the Listing table how can I get it to update both without doing this with raw SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, I have changed the update function to:

```
function updatePoi(){
        $left = $_POST['left'];
        $top = $_POST['top'];
        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        DB::query('UPDATE "Listing" SET "Left"='.$left.', "Top"='.$top.' WHERE "ID"='.$id);
        DB::query('UPDATE "Listing_Live" SET "Left"='.$left.', "Top"='.$top.' WHERE "ID"='.$id);
        return 'success';
    }
```

I'd be happy to hear of a tidier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest using

```
$poi->Top = $top;
$poi->write(); 
$poi->publish("Live", "Stage");
```